# Percentage Increase between the sum of two seperate sets of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking at calculating percentage change in excel between the sum of two numbers. Say for example, "=SUM(E141:M141)/SUM(Q141:Y141)-1". This works fine. However, if any of the sums above turn out to be zero, excel goes mental. I can adjust the formula to work with single cells but not with sums of two separate cells. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The single cell sentence confused me a bit. The percentage change of any value from 0 is infinite and arithmetically a division by 0. Did you try using the IFERROR() formula to handle this case?

Comment: I haven't used the IFERROR(). Is there a way to still get a figure for a percentage ecven though zero is invloved. Maybe produce a result of 0% for example instead of infinite. For the single cell sentence, I meant finding the change between A1 & B1 instead of 2 sets of summed up cells if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I am interpreting your question based on the formula you provided is:

> B is % of A different to A

For example two sums A = 20; B = 30 results in (30/20)-1=0.5. Essentially B is 50% different to A with respect to A.

As Robin Gertenbach mentioned you can use [IFERROR()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) to modify your formula into,

`=IFERROR(SUM(E141:M141)/SUM(Q141:Y141)-1, 0)`

edit: your last statement asks if you can still calculate a percentage even when one of the values is 0. The answer is no. The difference between a number and 0 is infinite, no other solution exists.

Comment: This sorts out the problem perfectly. Thanks,